# Are there any Atom ESlint or JSHint packages that show errors/warnings in terminal on command?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, jslint, developer-tools, eslint

I'm looking for either an ESLint or JSHint package for Atom that, like [this](https://atom.io/packages/jslint) package for JSLint, has an option for toggling when it will show the validation results, rather than doing it automatically upon saving.

Ideally, I would like the linter to run when I enter a command of my choice and show me all warnings/errors in a terminal popup.

Unfortunately, none the ESLint or JSHint packages for Atom that I've tried appear to offer this feature (they all automatically run either while the user types, or upon saving). Does anyone know any Atom packages that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Does it need to be an Atom package? You could just run ESLint from a terminal/prompt/cli: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

Comment: Hi @ZachButtram thanks for your comment. Ideally, I want an Atom package that does this but if I can't find one I will probably settle for running it from the terminal.